# install updates after dismissing the popup?

Tags: updates

The update green icon is the icon that pop-up and informs that you can install updates, or you can choose to be informed later.

I wanted to install them now, but I accidentally clicked "Remind me later", instead of "Install now".

How to summon the icon again so I can do the right thing?

Answer (score 1):

The application you are talking about is called "Software Updater". Just open the dash, type "software updater" and run it.